# How to print 4 pages tiled across in landscape in Word?

Tags: microsoft-word

I'm trying to print 4 individual 8.5 × 2.75 pages tiled across 1 regular 8.5 × 11 sheet of paper in landscape format.

What's the best way to do so? When I select "Print options" → "4 pages to one sheet" it doesn't come out right.

Would placing the individual pages into columns solve this?

Comment: If what you want is a 4-page column, best to take the most direct approach and make a 4-page column at the outset.

Answer (score 1):

My preference would be to insert a 4x1 table as I find that easier for control of the aesthetics of the layout. Using columns, any change in the first column may 'rearrange' all four columns, whereas in a table each 'column' is effectively isolated from the others. (The table borders can be removed after layout is settled, or left if suitable for guillotining.)